# Cannot launch apps - Maximum number of clients reached

Tags: 14.04, xorg, 64-bit

I am having a persistent issue launching apps in my newly installed ubuntu 14.04 install. Basically, everythign will be running fine for a while, but then when I attempt to open some apps (like the ghome calculator for instance) they dont launch. If I try to launch them from terminal however I will get errors like this:

```
Maximum number of clients reached
** (gcalctool:19516): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Maximum number of clients reached Cannot open display: 
Use 'gnome-calculator --help' to display help.
```

So far this has happened with Nemo, Gnome Calculator, and Libre Office

How can I destroy these ghost clients?

Where can I look to start to troubleshoot this error?

Comment: Start `lsof -U` and add the output in your question, if the problem occurs the next time.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BN10ZASE it looks like chrome and slack are all over the place which is weird. I have a couple chrome windows open, but only 14 tabs open. Then there is only one instance of slack open

Answer (score 0):

It seems the numbers for Chrome are normal (from your pastebin).
I think you should look at slack.
There are a couple of open issues on github about this problem like [Electron is leaking Xorg connections over time and on every desktop notification causing Xorg to stop accept clients](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2922).
There replied with saying it should be fixed in version 1.2.4 from [the slack website](https://slack.com/apps)

Comment: I switched to scudcloud, I'll see if that does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in another thread, this helpt me!

```
sudo ss -x src "*/tmp/.X11-unix/*" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\s*$" | while read port
do sudo ss -p -x | grep -w $port | grep -v X11-unix 
done | grep -Eo '".+"' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

- ss is a tool to investigate sockets
- `sudo ss -x src "*/tmp/.X11-unix/*"` lists to calls that are binded
  to x11.
- `grep...` Then grapping the number of port
- `while read port` means take the given port number and feed it to...
- `sudo ss -p -x | grep -w $port | grep -v X11-unix  done` which will grep these port binded to x11 giving the name of the process, and then
- `sort | uniq -c | sort -rn` sorting them in decreasing order based on how many exists in a given socket of system.

A simplified version which shows the first 10 processes that have open the most sockets to the system.

`sudo ss -p -x |  grep -Eo '".+"' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 10`

By knowing which process occupies the most sockets in the system, you can simply kill it. eg. `killall process_name` which will free sockets in your system to be used from other programs. The number of sockets in linux system are limited (but you can change its number - see links).

Related articles / bugs: [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455004) and [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/9094)

Comment: Could you explain the script and why / how it solves the problem?